# java.io.FileNotFoundException "Access is denied"

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, filenotfoundexception

I have the following code:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(
        "C:/Users/SW-FRMV-268347L/OUTPUTADDONGROSSPRICE.xlsx"));
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/SW-FRMV-268347L/new.xlsx");

XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Options CD DPV");
XSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(2);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);

cell.setCellValue("Bharthan");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

When I am trying to save a file, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\SW-FRMV-268347L\new.xlsx (Access is denied)
```

**Note:** i am use `org.apache.poi 4.0.1 version`

Comment: Do you have write right to this file location? [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html) states that the reason for this exception is `if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason`.

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't the file get blocked if it is already open in Excel? Other thing could be that you don't have permission write to that file (read-only).

Comment: Seems some other application (Excel?) has locked the file.